# Why are jconsole and Tomcat Manager page memory stats so different?

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory, jconsole

I'm trying to investigate heap memory leaks, and in order to do so, I'm looking at a bunch of tools. One thing that catches my attention is the wild difference between memory measurements done by Sun's jconsole on one hand and Tomcat's Manager page on the other.

Consider this:

[image: jconsole screenshot]

Compared to this:

[image: tomcat manager screenshot]

All figures shown in the manager are off and seem completely unrelated. On this server, Tomcat7 (7.0.50) is the only java application running. Which one should I trust?

In case that matters, I run this java:

```
[bin]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

If you need more info, just ask me.

Comment: Maybe Mb=Megabits and MB=MegaBytes difference? If you want numbers from third profiler use also $java/bin/jvisualvm tool.

Comment: They all call the platform MXBeans provided by the JVM itself, so they should show the same data. My guess is that you;ve made the measurements at different time.